# Matching line number with string in a table.

Tags: python

I have a file with a list of columns describing particular parameters:

size    magnitude    luminosity

I need only particular data (in particular lines, and columns) from this file. So far I have a code in python, where I have appended the necessary line numbers. I just need to know how i can match it to get the right string in the text file along with just the variables in columns (magnitude) and (luminosity.) Any suggestions on how I could approach this?

Here is a sample of my code (#comments describe what I have done and what I want to do):

```
temp_ListMatch = (point[5]).strip() 
if temp_ListMatch:
    ListMatchaddress = (point[5]).strip()
    ListMatchaddress = re.sub(r'\s', '_', ListMatchaddress) 
    ListMatch_dirname = '/projects/XRB_Web/apmanuel/499/Lists/' + ListMatchaddress
    #print ListMatch_dirname+"\n" 

    try:
        file5 = open(ListMatch_dirname, 'r')
    except IOError:
        print 'Cannot open: '+ListMatch_dirname

    Optparline = []
    for line in file5:
        point5 = line.split()
        j = int(point5[1])
        Optparline.append(j)
        #Basically file5 contains the line numbers I need, 
        #and I have appended these numbers to the variable j. 
        temp_others = (point[4]).strip()
        if temp_others: 
            othersaddress = (point[4]).strip()
            othersaddress =re.sub(r'\s', '_', othersaddress) 
            othersbase_dirname = '/projects/XRB_Web/apmanuel/499/Lists/' + othersaddress
            try:
                file6 = open(othersbase_dirname, 'r')
            except IOError:
                print 'Cannot open: '+othersbase_dirname

            gmag = []
            z = []
            rh = []
            gz = []

            for line in file6:
                point6 = line.split()
                f = float(point6[2])
                g = float(point6[4])
                h = float(point6[6])
                i = float(point6[9])
         # So now I have opened file 6 where this list of data is, and have
        # identified the columns of elements that I need. 
        # I only need the particular rows (provided by line number) 
        # with these elements chosen. That is where I'm stuck!
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not increment a number every new line you check? You can use that line to index a dictionary when adding the line's contents, decide if you need a line or not, etc

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that you have one file containing lines in the format `size magnitude luminosity`, and another file with a list of row numbers? And that you want to extract only the magnitude and luminosity columns for the specified lines?

Comment: What is `point`?? What is it holding??

Comment: @AdamObeng yes I have a file containing size magntidue luminostiy, and another fiel with a list of row numbers. I want to extract only the magnitude and luminosity columns for the specified lines.

Comment: @Schoolboy point is defined by the linesplit and helps identify elements of the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Load the whole data file in to a pandas DataFrame (assuming that the data file has a header from which we can get the column names)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file')
```

Load the file of line numbers into a pandas Series (assuming there's one per line):

```
#  squeeze = True makes the function return a series
row_numbers = pd.read_csv('/path/to/rows_file', squeeze = True)
```

Return only those lines which are in the row number file, and the columns magnitude and luminosity (this assumes that the first row is numbered 0):

```
relevant_rows = df.ix[row_numbers][['magnitude', 'luminosity']
```